# Jenkinsのデプロイ先サーバを確認する方法は？

Tags: jenkins, デプロイ

今業務でJenkinsを使っています。
その時にどのサーバーにプロジェクトがdeployされるのか知りたいです。

JenkinsにつないだURLの↓この太字の部分をsshでサーバーに入ればいいのだと思ったんですが
http://**hoge-hoge101z.stg.jp.local**:9999/jenkins/job/unit-test

Jenkinsはクラスタリングができるため、必ずしもこのサーバーに成果物があるとは限らないと聞きました。どうすればJenkinsのdeploy先のserverを知ることができますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まずは
jenkinsのスレーブの状況を確認するためには「Jenkinsの管理>ノードの管理」で確認できます。
現在見ているJenkinsサーバがどのようなスレーブ構成で動いていて、どのビルドが動いているのか確認できるでしょう。

またJenkins自体が他のサーバでSSHで入ってデプロイ作業をしている可能性もありますので
念の為各ビルドでやっていることも確認してください。
場合によってはJenkinsがおけないサーバですとリモートでデプロイを実行することもあります。

またJenkinsが他にもいくつも立ち上がっている可能性もあります。
その場合はJenkinsのPayload URLが各GitサービスのWebhookに登録されていないか確認しましょう。